# Add delete and edit buttons in Data Table

Tags: javascript

[Attaching picture to give a rough idea about the flow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mf7g.png)

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/NewPopulation',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    var tr;
                    console.log(data);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        tr = tr + "<tr>";
                        tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].PollSurveyName + "</td>";
                        tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].PollSurveyDescription + "</td>";
                        tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].CategoryName + "</td>";
                        tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].StartDate + "</td>";
                        tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].EndDate + "</td>";
                        tr = tr + "</tr>";
                    }
                    $('#tblPopulation').append(tr);
                    tblFormate();
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('No Valid Data');
                }
            });

            function tblFormate() {
                var table = $('#tblPopulation').DataTable(
                    {
                        //"searching": false,
                        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 50, 100, 150, -1], [5, 10, 50, 100, 150, "All"]]
                    });
                //Apply the search
                table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
                    $('input', table.column(colIdx).header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                        table
                            .column(colIdx)
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

    <thead>
                                        <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                                            <td>Poll/Survey Name</td>
                                            <td>Description</td>
                                            <td>Category Name</td>
                                            <td>Start Date</td>
                                            <td>End Date</td>
                                        </tr>
    </thead>
```

This is Java Script code and html code for my Data Table and I want to add a column having Delete and Edit button. For delete button the record must be deleted and for edit button it would populated 4 dropdowns for Poll/Survey Name, Description, Category Name, Start Date, End date.[Attaching picture to give a rough idea about the flow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpVsk.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far - what are the roadblocks you've run into?

Comment: It's easy. When you start to populate the `grid`, you need to add two `<tr>` after the `EndDate` field (maybe something like this: `tr = tr + "<td>" + <button /> + "</td>";`. Obviously inside the `button` tag pass the ID of the record and a function that calls your method to edit or delete. BTW, before to post a question here try by yourself all the possibilities. If you don't get anything, then post here :)

Comment: Could you please add the Response which you get after ajax call, and also add some data for your all dropdown ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance having difficulty in adding a column with edit and delete button. Getting syntax error in that for loop.

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra that ajax call has populated the table. After adding edit button when i select a row to edit it must populate below dropdowns. Please refer the image attached. Currently i selected poll name from dropdown to populate other dropdown but after adding edit button all dropdowns must b populated by that button click.

Comment: Inside of your loop add 2 new TD with same row and add button code and after your loop bind those button click event using JQuery, It will solve your problem

Comment: @ArCiGo even i have that common sense to copy already written lines and just to put a button tag. :D but I'm getting syntax error for everything i tried and getting against what u just told me to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual way would be

Add 2 column in your Table Header

```
<tr style="font-weight:bold">
    <td>Poll/Survey Name</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Category Name</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
</tr>
```

Similarly add logic to add buttons in your data loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = tr + "<tr>";
    tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].PollSurveyName + "</td>";
    tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].PollSurveyDescription + "</td>";
    tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].CategoryName + "</td>";
    tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].StartDate + "</td>";
    tr = tr + "<td>" + data[i].EndDate + "</td>";

    tr = tr + "<td><input type='button' val='Edit' /></td>";
    tr = tr + "<td> <input type='button' val='Delete' /> </td>";

    tr = tr + "</tr>";
}
```

Or better way is use this [link](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,  // Column index position
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>" // Button detail
        } ]
    } );

    // Handle button click event
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        alert( data[0] +"'s salary is: "+ data[ 5 ] );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: the 'For Loop' method

Comment: I think val='Edit' and delete was problem. Have changed it. try now. I would suggest try 2nd option its way better

Comment: For 2nd option i have some doubts. Like what i must write for "ajax:"

Comment: ajax would be '/Home/NewPopulation',  Did 1st approach worked. its just some syntax issue. have a look carefullly

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. But i'm getting blank buttons :D no label nothing

Comment: thats serious issue. :) val='Edit' will be value='Edit'.      Mark as accepted if this works and can upvote too

Comment: Yeah solved. Thankyou. Just for info is there anyway to put anything like image button. For e.g instead of Button with label 'Delete' can i put a button having icon of Bin.

Comment: ya you can but img instead of button. you can customize based in req